# Add multiple values in id attribute of glink tag

Tags: grails, gsp

Is it possible to add multiple values in the `id` attribute of `glink` tag?

I want to get a url like: `/place/view/home/7?` (/< controller >/< action >/< name >/< id >?params)

is it possible with `glink` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for is the `params` option,

```
<g:link controller="cname" action="act" id="1" params="[sort: 'title']" />
```

Comment: or even <g:link controller="cname" action="act" params="[id:1,paramOne:1,paramTwo:2,paramThree:3]" />

Comment: Yes, I know this solution, but I want a google friendly url as result without params.

Comment: hmmm...then consider using `URL Mappings` with embedded variables - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#embeddedVariables

Answer (score 0):

I use the following solution in Grails v2.4.3:

In UrlMappings.groovy, I added:

```
static mappings = {
    ...
    name dualId: "/$controller/$action/$id/$id2?(.$format)?" {}

    /* Usage:
     *  <g:link mapping="dualId" action="myMethod" params='[id2: "${id2Value}"]'>
     *    Accept id AND id2
     *  </g:link>

     *  Generates following link in the UI: 
     *    <a href="/myController/myMethod/142/387">Accept id AND id2</a>
     *  SPECIAL NOTE: params='[id2: "${id2Value}"]' works.
     *    using: params="[id2: '${id2Value}']" DOES NOT WORK!
     */
    ...
}
```

For your requirements, "/place/view/home/7? (/< controller >/< action >/< name >/< id >?params)", you could use:

```
static mappings = {
    ...
    name placeViewHome: "/$controller/$action/$name/$id?" {}

    /* Usage:
     *  <g:link mapping="placeViewHome" action="myAction" params='[name: "${nameValue}", q: "str"]'>
     *    Accept name AND id
     *  </g:link>

     *  Should generate the following link in the UI: 
     *    <a href="/myController/myMethod/myName/387?q=str">Accept name AND id</a>
     *  I didn't try it, but you should be able to add in other params and I would expect them to appear after the question mark as usual.
     */
    ...
}
```

See Grails documentation, [8.4.11 Named URL Mappings](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/single.html#namedMappings), for more detail...

Note: In the g:link, the order of the quotes mattered, double quotes inside single quotes worked, but not the other way around.